# Need help on how to do callback in Angular

Tags: angular

```
  async getExample(value: string) {
    // this must be done first
    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.location.nativeElement.classList.add('fadeMeOut');    
    }
    // this must be done second
    switch (value) {
      case this.tag[0]: {
        await this.getAlbum();
        break;
      }
      default: {
        //statements; 
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

I would like to use callback feature to fix the problem but I don't know how.
basically, I would like to get the first part done completely and it moves on to the second part.

The logic is to call the first part and callback the second part.
I appreciate very much for any helps.
Thank you.

Comment: It is executed from top to bottom already, so what is the problem ? do you want to wait for animation to end first (fadeMeOut looks like animation related class)

Comment: The first part is not done asynchronously

Comment: Yes, I would like to wait until the end of animation done first and then it will do the second part.  The second part will create the same componentRef and set the class to 'fadeMeIn'.  Basically, the second part destroys every thing if there is no wait in between the two process.  See additional code below or see the entire code in my repo https://github.com/d052057/lazycomponent.